# Redirect to https gives strange results

Tags: apache, redirect, https

I want to redirect all http requests to https.

In my webspace, I have the following structure:

```
/
/project1
/project2
/project2/.htaccess
/project2/index.html
```

In my **.htaccess**, I have the following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I call http://example.com, I get redirected to https://example.com - as expected.

When I call http://www.example.com, I get redirected to https://example.com/**project2** - not as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

I want all requests to get redirected to https://www.

http://example.com → https://example.com

http://www.example.com → https://www.example.com

https://example.com → https://www.example.com

Comment: There must be something more involved here than just this .htaccess; do you have different virtual host configurations for `example.com` and `www.example.com`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.